# How to pass String value to Collection? in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections, ranorex

This is my code:

```
List<string> deviceScreenshot=new List<string>(); 
List<string> fiddlerScreenshot=new List<string>();

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(summary[3].ToString())==false)
    deviceScreenshot=summary[3];
else
    deviceScreenshot="Screenshot not found";

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(summary[4].ToString())==false)
    fiddlerScreenshot=summary[4];
else
    fiddlerScreenshot="Screenshot not found";
```

I am getting the following error message!

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' (CS0029) -
>   D:\automation\OmnitureStatistics\OmnitureStatistics\TeardownUserCode.cs:144,23

Kindly tell me the solution for this!!

Comment: What is `deviceScreenshot`

Comment: It is list<string>   - List<string> deviceScreenshot=new List<string>();
    List<string> fiddlerScreenshot=new List<string>();

Comment: if `deviceScreenshot` is collection then you add like this 'deviceScreenshot.add(summary[3]);`

Comment: Not relevant to question here but you can make your if condition looks like `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(summary[3].ToString()))` instead of `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(summary[3].ToString())==false)` to make it little bit better looking.

Comment: Hi @Rahul, It really works.. Thank you :)...  what is the difference between 'deviceScreenshot.add(summary[3]);' and 'deviceScreenshot=summary[3];'

Comment: If you want to add values to collection then you have to use Add() method. If it is string then you can directly assign to it. Please find my update answer, where I added MSDN link for List<T>

Comment: @JenishRabadiya, Thank you very much.. I am using that ! ...

Comment: @RahulNikate, thankz for the link...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `Add()` method of the `List<T>` like below.

```
  List<string> deviceScreenshot=new List<string>();
  List<string> fiddlerScreenshot=new List<string>();


  if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(summary[3].ToString())==false)
      deviceScreenshot.Add(summary[3]);
  else
      deviceScreenshot.Add("Screenshot not found");

  if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(summary[4].ToString())==false)
      fiddlerScreenshot.Add(summary[4]);
  else
      fiddlerScreenshot.Add("Screenshot not found");
```

[Here's the MSDN link for more information on List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This code does not compile!
deviceScreenshot.Add(deviceScreenshot=summary[3]);

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Add() method of the List class. That's how you add items to a list.

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(summary[3].ToString())==false)
    deviceScreenshot.Add(summary[3]);
else
    deviceScreenshot.Add("Screenshot not found");

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(summary[4].ToString())==false)
    fiddlerScreenshot.Add(summary[4]);
else
    fiddlerScreenshot.Add("Screenshot not found");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could move the logic to a helper method and save the static string in a resource file.

If summary is a list or array if string, then you do not need to call ToString().

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {    
        new Program().AddStringToCollection();
    }             

    private void AddStringToCollection()
    {
        var summary = new string[] {"A", "B", "C", "", "D"};

        var deviceScreenshot = new List<string>();
        var fiddlerScreenshot = new List<string>();

        AppendExceptWhiteSpace(deviceScreenshot, summary[3]);
        AppendExceptWhiteSpace(fiddlerScreenshot, summary[4]);
    }

    //move to a resource file if possible
    const string NotFoundText = "Screenshot not found";

    //in a utility class this could also be an extension method
    private void AppendExceptWhiteSpace(List<string> list, string value)
    {
        //not sure if you want empty strings, otherwise change back to IsNullOrEmpty
        string text = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) 
                ? NotFoundText 
                : value;

        list.Add(text);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is "summary", it wasn't mention, so I will see it as list of parameter.

1. your comparing will always do the same cause you are missing "":
   summary[3].ToString())=="false" // string to string.
2. adding to list should be like:
   deviceScreenshot.Add(summary[3].ToString());
   I know most answer but somehow they forgot "ToString()" here (unless it is a string list. in this case remove the "ToString()" in both cases.